# How to change image stored in document library

Tags: document-library, document

I created a document library in sharepoint 2013 and am using the library to store records that contains an image and a title each. My question is How do I change/edit the image/file uploaded for each record after uploading.

Comment: You question is not clear. Can you please rephrase and add more details.

Comment: Do you want to update the properties or the image file ? Please can you clarify ?

Comment: I just want to be able to replace the uploaded image from time to time because the site is a public facing website